# Is it possible to parse multi-line c style comments in MGrammar?

Tags: mgrammar

I've been hacking around with the May09 Oslo bits, experimented with tokenizing some source code. I can't seem to figure out how to correctly handle multiline C-style comments though.
For example: `/*comment*/`

Some cases that elude me:

```
/***/
```

or

```
/**//**/
```

I can make one or the other work, but not both.
The grammar was:

```
    module Test {
    language Comments {

        token Comment =
            MultiLineComment;

        token MultiLineComment =
            "/*" MultiLineCommentChar* "*/";

        token MultiLineCommentChar =
            ^ "*" |
            "*" PostAsteriskChar;

        token PostAsteriskChar =
            ^ "*" |
            "*" ^("*" | "/"); 

        /*    
        token PostAsteriskChar =
            ^ "*" |
            "*" PostAsteriskChar; 
        */

        syntax Main = Comment*;
    }
}
```

The commented out token  is what I think I want to do, however recursive tokens are not permitted.
The fact that MGrammar itself has "broken" multiline comments (it can't handle `/***/`) leads me to believe this isn't possible.

Does anyone know otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done it is as follows (not all my own code but I can't find a referance to the original author).

```
interleave Skippable = Whitespace | Comment;
interleave Comment = CommentToken;
@{Classification["Comment"]}
token CommentToken = CommentDelimited
| CommentLine;
token CommentDelimited = "/*" CommentDelimitedContent* "*/";
token CommentDelimitedContent
= ^('*')
| '*'  ^('/');
token CommentLine = "//" CommentLineContent*;
token CommentLineContent
= ^(
'\u000A' // New Line
|  '\u000D' // Carriage Return
|  '\u0085' // Next Line
|  '\u2028' // Line Separator
|  '\u2029' // Paragraph Separator
);
```

This allows for both single line (`//`) comments as well as multiline (`/* */`) comments.

Comment: This fails the first of the two cases that I provided.